# Where is the usefulness of Fourier Transform I was promised?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, applications

Before I started my PDE course I heard about Fourier Transform and how useful it is (waves, heat problem, etc) but I recently finished it and all we did is solve some PDE problems where we had to apply a Fourier Transform and then solve some related ODEs.

So my question is: ¿Where is all the magic I was promised? I was told Fourier Transform can **convert a complex wave into the basic ones. ¿How is this done?**

I really need some insight in this topic because I'm really interested and I feel my course didn't cover any applications of the Fourier Transform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Where is all the magic I was promised" you just said that you used the Fourier transform to convert a pde into an ode you can solve. Is that not magic to you? How else were you going to solve that pde?

Comment: I can only second the previous commenter. Transferring a PDE to an ODE (e.g. "getting rid" of a spatial laplacian) is a HUGE deal. If that doesnt entertain you, I am afraid nothing will.... ;-)

Comment: That was a retorical question, my true question was ¿how can you convert a complex wave into the basic ones using Fourier transform?

Comment: A Fourier transform is used in a whole lot of different ways, but the principle idea is that you can reduce most problems in really complicated systems to questions about one sine function input. Performing the Fourier transform certainly is useful, but it's main usage is in signal processing. Using Fourier's theorem, that any function is a sum of sine waves (or sine and cosine with no phase shift, or complex exponentials), thats where the magic is

Comment: Thank you sam, I will get to complex analysis next year so I hope we can cover some of the ideas you gave me.  You were really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

The Fourier transform turns the differentiation operator into multiplication, which can be viewed as a diagonalization of the differentiation operator. This eventually led to defining diagonalization of matrices through eigenvectors, which is where all that magic came from. Oddly enough, the infinite-dimensional magic came first and gave rise to the finite-dimensional magic.

Do you believe that diagonalization of Hermitian matrix is interesting, useful or even powerful? If so, then you should really appreciate the infinite-dimensional diagonalization of the differentiation operator through integral "sums" instead of finite sums. Of course you might not believe either is very interesting, in which case, a lot of modern Math will be boring to you.

The diagonalization of a Hermitian matrix with orthnormal basis $\{e_n\}$ of eigenfunctions with eigenvalues $\lambda_n$:
$$
                    x = \sum_{n}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n\\
                     \|x\|^2=\sum_{n}|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2 \\
                 Ax = \sum_{n}\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
The diagonalization of $D=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by exponentials $e_s(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{isx}$ using a complex inner product:
$$
            f = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \langle f,e_{s}\rangle e_s dx \\
      \|f\|^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\langle f,e_{s}\rangle|^2ds \\
         Df = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} s\langle f,e_s\rangle e_s
$$
Diagonalization is a useful concept that came out of this infinite-dimensional context and filtered down to the finite-dimensional.

Comment: Just to add to this, once you know some abstract properties of the Fourier transform (it is unitary), you may compute the spectrum (which is in general a more complicated task in infinite dimensions) of the momentum operator, $-i\frac{d}{dx}$ on the full line, a physically interesting problem. It also informs the abstract development of the spectral theorem, as an explicitly computable example